# If a warlock with the Repelling Blast invocation casts Eldritch Blast and hits, must the targets always be pushed back?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, cantrips, forced-movement, eldritch-invocations

If a warlock with the Repelling Blast eldritch invocation casts *eldritch blast* and hits, must the targets always be pushed back? Or can you choose not to push back the target?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### You don't have to push

The wording on Repelling Blast is (emphasis mine):

> When you hit a creature with *eldritch blast*, you **can** push
>   the creature up to 10 feet away from you in a straight line.
>
> --- *Player's Handbook*, p. 111

The **can** here functions as an optional, meaning you are free not to do it. If that word had been omitted you would have no choice, but it's there so you do.

Comment: Does the "can" also influence the "up to", so that the caster could choose, for example, to push the target just 5 feet away?

Comment: @Kirt Presumably yes, but it also covers the creature hitting something on the way.